# Mysql simple table

Tags: mysql

Please help, I need to create a database for car dealership. Database has to contain all the employees in the shop and all cars in the shop. Also base has to contain info on which car is sold and which employee has sold that car.

I have made the table, but i cannnot connect sold car and employee that sold that car.

**Script:**

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `classicmodels` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `classicmodels`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.13, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: classicmodels
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.73-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `cars`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cars`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `carID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `modelName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`carID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cars`
--

LOCK TABLES `cars` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cars` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cars` VALUES (1,'Volkswagen','Jetta',13300),(2,'Renault','Laguna',14700),(3,'Ford','Focus',13600),(4,'Daewoo','Tico',1100),(5,'Toyota','Avensis',14500),(6,'Alfa Romeo','156',8700),(7,'Volkswagen','Passat',22200),(8,'Renault','Clio',6400),(9,'Ford','Fiesta',6900),(10,'Daewoo','Cielo',3600),(11,'Toyota','Rav4',24900),(12,'Alfa Romeo','147',7500),(13,'Volkswagen','Golf',16700),(14,'Renault','Megane',11400),(15,'Ford','Mondeo',14600),(16,'Daewoo','Matiz',1700),(17,'Toyota','Yaris',7400),(18,'Alfa Romeo','159',17000),(19,'Volkswagen','Polo',6500),(20,'Renault','Scenic',6800),(21,'Ford','Escort',2000),(22,'Daewoo','Espero',2500),(23,'Toyota','Corolla',10300),(24,'Alfa Romeo','166',5200);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cars` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `employees`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeID`),
  KEY `prodaja_idx` (`employeeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employees`
--

LOCK TABLES `employees` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `employees` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (1,'Brkic','Goran','goran@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Direktor'),(2,'Milosevic','Srdjan','srdjan@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Marketing'),(3,'Srdic','Boro','boro@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Marketing'),(4,'Marinkovic','Marin','marin@cprodavnicaautomobila.com','Menadzer prodaje'),(5,'Nemanjic','Tamara','tamara@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac'),(6,'Kuduz','Renato','renato@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac'),(7,'Salkovic','Vladimir','vladimir@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac'),(8,'Berin','Marko','marko@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac'),(9,'Konjevic','Srecko','srecko@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac'),(10,'Pajic','Sasa','sasa@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac'),(11,'Goranovic','Milan','milan@prodavnicaautomobila.com','Prodavac');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `employees` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `soldcars`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `soldcars`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `soldcars` (
  `carID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empoyeeID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`carID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `soldcars`
--

LOCK TABLES `soldcars` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `soldcars` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `soldcars` VALUES (1,'kuduz'),(2,'brkic'),(4,'goranovic'),(5,'milosevic'),(12,'pajic');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `soldcars` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2014-03-04 18:47:40
```

Comment: In what way can't you connect them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql basic table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179498/mysql-basic-table)

Comment: Check your table sold car has `empoyeeid` instead of `employeeid`

Comment: Was it correct or you are working on it

Comment: Thanx for the help it was  syntax error.

Comment: If your previous question is closed, please edit it and do not ask the same question again.

Answer (score 2):

Check your table sold car has empoyeeid instead of employeeid.  That is why you are not able to connect

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeID`),
  KEY `prodaja_idx` (`employeeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;    

CREATE TABLE `soldcars` (
  `carID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empoyeeID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`carID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```